# echoving new selected attribute in Magento created using setup script

Tags: magento-1.9

I create custom attribute for customer using installer script it worked.
now i want to echo selected attribute here is my approach

my installer script

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'gender', array(
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Gender',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'required'      => false,
    'sort_order'    => 9,
    'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'option'     => array (
        'values' => array(
            0 => 'Mail',
            1 => 'Femail',

        )
    ),
));

if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.6.0', '<='))
{
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
      $attrSetId = $customer->getResource()->getEntityType()->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
      $setup->addAttributeToSet('customer', $attrSetId, 'General', 'gender');
}
if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(), '1.4.2', '>='))
{
    Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'gender')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create','customer_account_edit','checkout_register'))
    ->save();
}
```

This is my phtml file

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
  <option value="1" <?php if($this->getCustomer()->getGender()==1){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> >Mail</option>
  <option value="0" <?php if($this->getCustomer()->getGender()==0){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>Femail</option>
</select>
```

But when i echoing value  using **$this->getCustomer()->getGender()** it gives  null.how I get selected value after save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Srinith,i does not know why,**you have create gender attribute for customer**.As you have **using magento 1.9 it already exit as an attribute at customer**.you **just need to enable it setting from backend**.

May **be this setting you cannot get this attribute**.

For,for enable  this,you need to go at  **admin>System>Customer> Customer Configuration >Name and Address Options >Show Gender**  make it **Yes**